# Массив байтов кодировка

Tags: java, массивы, кодировка

Проблема с кодировкой массива, как можно исправить?

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException { 
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("Z:/xsd/java2.txt"));

    byte[] filedata = IOUtils.toByteArray(fis);
    String utf = new String(filedata, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println("String created from byte array in UTF-8 encoding : " + utf);
    fis.close();

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Z:/xsd/1.txt" );
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(utf);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();

}
```

Проблема именно при записи. Читает и выводит нормально, но когда делаю output — каракули!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
    new FileOutputStream("outfilename"), "UTF-8"));
try {
    out.write(aString);
} finally {
    out.close();
}
```

Как то так

Comment: Если использовать такой вывод также проблема с кодировкой тут не знаете как?! FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(new File("Z:/xsd/as/1.txt"), Charset.isSupported("UTF-8"));
            ObjectOutputStream objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutput);

Answer (score 3):

Когда вы используете ObjectOutputStream – вы записываете бинарные данные. Этот вариант OutputStream'а предназначен для сохранения объектов, которые будут потом читаться из ObjectInputStream'а.

Если хочется писать именно строку в UTF-8, то лучше использовать `Writer/BufferedWriter`:

```
try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("some path"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
  writer.write("some java string");
}
```

Стоит также учитывать, что значительное число программ под MS Windows будут пытаться читать текстовые файлы в cp1251 вместо utf8, если в начале не присутствует BOM, закодированный в utf8 (при выводе можно сделать `writer.write("\ufeff");`, что реально запишет три байта: `0xef 0xbb 0xbf`). Так себя ведёт, например, MS Excel при работе с csv/tsv/ssv.

Answer (score 2):

ObjectOutputStream - это класс для сериализации произвольных объектов. Он естественно будет выводить всякую ерунду.

Пользуйтесь для вывода тем же методом что и для загрузки. Т.е.

```
byte[] filedata = utf.getBytes("UTF-8"); // преобразование строки в массив байт в нужной кодировке
fos.write(filedata); // пишем массив целиком в файл.
```

Либо воспользуйтесь чем-нибудь вроде PrintWriter для записи строк.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте это:

```
String utf = new String(random, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: читает и выводит отлично а именно при записи карякулы на кирилические символы.